# How to use installation configured variables in setup project?

Tags: .net, setup-project

Using .net's setup project, I want to write the location that my software is installed to into the registry, in order to help a plugin know where the main application is. Is there some kind of %variable% I can use which represents the folder to which the application was installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the properties for Application Folder in File System view, it has a property called "Property" with value "TARGETDIR". You can use [TARGETDIR] in any of the other views to represent the chosen installation directory.